# API Design - create 2 different resources on one route

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api, rest, routes

I'm designing an API to be used with a mobile app, and I'm stuck with one particular requirement. There's one case where I'll need to create two different resources, and I would prefer to do that with one HTTP request, so I don't have to mess with multiple requests and callbacks, etc.

To simplify, I have one resource called Buckets and one called Apples. Buckets contain many Apples, and Buckets can also be named by the user. The user names a Bucket, and then throughout the app, can assign different Apples instances to that particular bucket.

I'm unclear how to create my route If the user is looking at an Apple and wants to assign it to a Bucket with a brand new name. In this case, my route would have to first create the Bucket with the new name, and then add the Apple to that Bucket.

Some of the routes I have so far are:

```
POST /buckets                    # create a new bucket
POST /buckets/:bucket_id/apples  # create a new apple within an existing bucket
```

What would this hybrid route look like? Perhaps something like:

```
POST /buckets/new/apples         # post data would contain NAME of new bucket and ID of apple
```

Open to any suggestions, but to reiterate, I'd really like to do all this in one HTTP request. Not sure if that breaks the RESTful design pattern or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what I'm looking for is Nested Attributes.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1